# Using Docker ADD command for multiples files

Tags: regex, docker

I want to copy some files to my images and I wan to use the ADD command. I read in the Docker documentation about regular expression for ADD, but I don't know what kind of expression can I use?

I want something like this

```
FROM registry:5000/ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Me

# some stuffs 

ADD Sources/{file1,file2,load_file} /etc/Sources/

# more stuffs
```

Note: the expression is wrong but I did it to show you what I expect from the ADD command. (I did it thinking in shell regular expressions).

So, How can I do that? I can not access to the link [filepath.Match](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath#Match). If anyone have these rules, please let me know?

### Update

I am using [this Docker docs reference](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add)

I am using this version:

```
Client version: 1.3.0
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): c78088f
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.3.0
Server API version: 1.15
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): c78088f
```

Comment: could you link to the documentation bit that describes the usage of regex for the `ADD` instruction?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [`ADD`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add) command and [`COPY`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy) both allow Golang's [`filepath.Match` wildcards](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match)

You can find a number of examples in the test code for Go: https://golang.org/src/pkg/path/filepath/match_test.go

Rules reproduced here for those in China who can't access Google/golang.org:

```
    '*'         matches any sequence of non-Separator characters
    '?'         matches any single non-Separator character
    '[' [ '^' ] { character-range } ']'
                character class (must be non-empty)
    c           matches character c (c != '*', '?', '\\', '[')
    '\\' c      matches character c

character-range:
    c           matches character c (c != '\\', '-', ']')
    '\\' c      matches character c
    lo '-' hi   matches character c for lo <= c <= hi
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually, you would end up putting all the relevant files into a sub-directory, and then just `ADD` that directory, to bring them into the image.

Comment: I want to add the only specific files, I don't want to ADD the all directory :(

Answer (score 2):

Example how add files with ext .so to directory:

```
ADD modules/*.so /usr/local/apache2/modules/
```

or you can add all files in directory

```
ADD modules/* /usr/local/apache2/modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that in `ADD` you can provide an `url`. And in `url` you **won't** be able to do something like:

`ADD http://myStorage.com/something/*.jar /dir1/dirb`