# Wget numeric pattern in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, wget, dockerfile

Under Linux bash, I can use numeric pattern to download multiple files containing sequential number in the urls with one wget command, such as

```
wget https://example.com/file.zip00{1..4}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in Dockerfile where it seems to simply treat the pattern in curly braces as literals and thus leads to 404 not found.

Is there a way to fix it in Dockerfile?

Comment: put into sh script, `COPY` to container and run it?

Comment: I guess that should work, but I was wondering if there is any solution even simpler, without the need to ship extra files along with Dockerfile in order to build the image.

Comment: not sure if the escape character applies https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#escape try `wget https://example.com/file.zip00\{1..4}`

Comment: I tried, but did not work.

Comment: I have the following line in a Dockerfile which works fine, but is is not the same `RUN version=$(wget -q -O- http://captvty.fr/ | grep -o -m 1 'captvty-.*.zip' | sed 's/captvty-\(.*\).zip/\1/') && wget -O /dev/null http://captvty.fr/ && wget -O /tmp/Captvty.zip http://captvty.fr/?captvty-$version.zip && unzip -d  ~/Captvty /tmp/Captvty.zip && rm /tmp/Captvty.zip`

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591862/using-docker-add-command-for-multiples-files  I guess it is not possible at the moment

Comment: I do not see your pattern matching at https://golang.org/src/path/filepath/match_test.go