# How do I copy dir instead of dir contents in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If I try to copy a dir using pattern matching dir contents is being copied, for eg:

```
COPY [^g]* /home/user/src/
```

and docker context dir has following structure:

```
abc
  dir1
  dir2
def
  dir3
  dir4
ghi
  dir5
  dir6
```

Docker filesystem looks like this:

```
home
  user
    src
      dir1
      dir2
      dir3
      dir4
```

but I want it to copy abc and def too, ie

```
home
  user
    src
      abc
        dir1
        dir2
      def
        dir3
        dir4
```

I don't want to individually copy abc and def, here there are only two of them for demostration.

EDIT: [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy), clearly states that content of dir will be copied and not the dir itself, so I don't think there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: is rsync -av source/ destination/ working in docker ?

Comment: as far as i understand, rsync is a bash command, i'm talking about building docker image from docker context.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591862/using-docker-add-command-for-multiples-files . your regex does not do what you think

Comment: I actually tried it, and only dir1,2,3,4 got copied and 5,6 were not copied.